# Username / password combination does not seem to work with Shiny log in page

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code that should build a basic login screen for a Shiny application (obviously there ways to make it better and more secure - but thats not for now).

```
#Server.R


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    if (user_input$authenticated == FALSE) {
      ##### UI code for login page
      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 2, offset = 5,
                 br(), br(), br(), br(),
                 uiOutput("uiLogin"),
                 uiOutput("pass")
          )
        )
      )
    } else {
      #### Your app's UI code goes here!
      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          # Slider input
          column(width = 4, offset = 5,
                 br(), br(),
                 uiOutput("obs"),
                 br(), br()
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(
          # Histogram output
          plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
      )
    }
  })

  output$obs <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1, max = 1000, value = 500)
  })

  # render histogram once slider input value exists
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$obs)
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), main = "")
  })

  user_input <- reactiveValues(authenticated = FALSE, valid_credentials = FALSE, 
                               user_locked_out = FALSE, status = "")


  observeEvent(input$login_button, {
    credentials <- readRDS("credentials/credentials.rds")

    row_username <- which(credentials$user == input$user_name)
    row_password <- which(credentials$pw == input$password) # digest() makes md5 hash of password

    if (length(row_username) == 1 && 
        length(row_password) == 1) {
        user_input$status <- "not"
        user_input$authenticated <- TRUE
    } else{
      user_input$status <- "not"
    }


    output$pass <- renderUI({

      if (user_input$status == "not") {
        h5(strong(paste0("No valid combination"), row_password, row_username))
      }

    })
  })

  output$uiLogin <- renderUI({
    wellPanel(
      textInput("user_name", "User Name:"),

      passwordInput("password", "Password:"),

      actionButton("login_button", "Log in")
    )
  })
})



UI.r
shinyUI(
  uiOutput("ui")
)
```

In the script and rds file is loaded. This .rds file can be reproduced with thefollowing code:

```
membership <- data.frame(
  user = c("kim", "sam", "john", "kelly", "ben", "joe"),
  company = c("", "DL", "AA", "UA", "US", "DL"),
  password = c("test1", "test1", "test1", "test1", "test1", "test1"),
  role = c("manager", rep("user", 5)))

  #Set wd of the folder  

setwd("~/credentials")
saveRDS(membership, "credentials.rds")
```

It all seems to work. However when I run it and enter "kim" / "test1" (which evaluates to - user_input$authenticated <- TRUE) I still got a message saying:

```
No valid combination 1 1
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: You have `user_input$status <- "not"` twice in your `server` code. Shouldn't it be `user_input$status <- "something else"` in case the login is successfull?